# Hibernate using OneToOne

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have two tables

```
tab1 { col1 (PK), col2, col3 }

tab2 { col1, col2(PK), col3 }
```

I am using Hibernate annotation for joining using "OneToOne"

I have the below Hibernate class for tab1

```
class tab1 {
   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "col2", referencedColumnName = "col1")
   private tab2 t2;
}
```

i was expecting to run the below sql

```
select * from tab1 t1, tab2 t2 where t1.col1 = t2.col2
```

But it is not working as i expected.Please help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve `tab1` entities and to eager load the associated `tab2` using a single select, use a "fetch" join:

```
SELECT t1 from Tab1 t1 left join fetch t1.t2
```

You need to think associations and to navigate through associations when working with an ORM.